# How to slice a rank 4 tensor in TensorFlow?

Tags: slice, tensorflow

I am trying to slice a four-dimensional tensor using the `tf.slice()` operator, as follows:

```
x_image = tf.reshape(x, [-1,28,28,1], name='Images_2D')
slice_im = tf.slice(x_image,[0,2,2],[1, 24, 24])
```

However, when I try to run this code, I get the following exception:

```
raise ValueError("Shape %s must have rank %d" % (self, rank))

ValueError: Shape TensorShape([Dimension(None), Dimension(28), Dimension(28), Dimension(1)]) must have rank 3
```

How can I slice this tensor?

Comment: @mrry Thank you for making question more precise.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [`tf.slice(input, begin, size)`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/slice) operator requires that the `begin` and `size` vectors—which define the subtensor to be sliced—have the same length as the number of dimensions in `input`. Therefore, to slice a 4-D tensor, you must pass a vector (or list) of four numbers as the second and third arguments of `tf.slice()`.

For example:

```
x_image = tf.reshape(x, [-1, 28, 28, 1], name='Images_2D')

slice_im = tf.slice(x_image, [0, 2, 2, 0], [1, 24, 24, 1])

# Or, using the indexing operator:
slice_im = x_image[0:1, 2:26, 2:26, :]
```

The indexing operator is slightly more powerful, as it can also reduce the rank of the output, if for a dimension you specify a single integer, rather than a range:

```
slice_im = x_image[0:1, 2:26, 2:26, :]
print slice_im_2d.get_shape()  # ==> [1, 24, 24, 1]

slice_im_2d = x_image[0, 2:26, 2:26, 0]
print slice_im_2d.get_shape()  # ==> [24, 24]
```

Comment: Is there a way to slice and maintain the `None` dimension? In other words something like, `tf.slice(x_image, [-1, 2, 2, 0], [1, 24, 24, 1])`

Comment: Yes, you can pass -1 as one of the elements of the `sizes` argument to `tf.slice()`. The TensorFlow indexing operator has recently been upgraded to support more of the NumPy-style slicing definitions, so you might find it easier to define a slice that way (e.g. it supports "unknown" start positions).

Comment: isn't it problematic that the starting index is still 0?

Comment: If you do `tf.slice(x, [0, …], [-1, …])` this defines the slice as including *every* row, unlike NumPy's slice semantics. The indexing operator (`x[0:-1, …]`) means "select all rows *except the last one*, as in NumPy.